# Grounding Metal Boxes to Outlets & Earth

Tags: grounding

I have some wiring questions.  These are my wiring options I have available & seeking some insight.  I am running a 30A 120v outlet From the 100A Box in the garage I will run 10-2 w/ground wire to the Metal Connection Box & GFCI Breaker in 100A Box for this circuit.  When I run the 10-2 w/ground to the connection box Should I ground that Metal Box w/That incoming Ground Wire?

That 2nd to last box is a 70A box that I'm using just for connecting the wires together there is no breakers or shut off here.  It has a blank cover that goes on the front.  This is simply my wiring "Connection Point".

However,  I have only 2 Wires coming out of that box out to the 30A RV outlet.  No ground Option available here.

Last, the 30A RV Outlet.  Should I run a ground rod here & Ground the Outlet & Metal Box?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You only have one neutral-earth bond in the entire system, at the main disconnect/breaker.

You have a 200A main panel.
A 100A subpanel.
A 70A disconnect switch.
And a 30A receptacle for the RV, which is inside a junction box.

The rule with metal junction boxes, you must attach the Equipment Grounding Conductor (ground) to the metal box *first*.  Once that is done, you can take it to the receptacle itself if the receptacle can't ground through its mounting frame for some reason.  (which it often can).

The run between the subpanel and disconnect needs to have its ground/earth wire attached to the metal chassis of the box, at both ends.  On the subpanel that will be the ground bar. On the disconnect box, you may need to add a lug. You cannot use neutral for this; neutral must be insulated from the box.

For the run from disconnect box to receptacle, if that is EMT, IMC or RMC metal conduit, or AC cable, then that provides the valid ground path and you do not need a ground wire.

Having *no ground/earth at all* to the RV connector is simply not allowed.

You cannot use a ground rod as a substitute for a ground wire. They don't do the same thing.  The ground rod is for equipotential bonding (including that thing I mentioned at the beginning). It helps with ESD. It does not help with human-generated electricity gone awry.  When combined with a GFCI it's better than having neither one... but it is still a far cry from Code requirements.

Comment: Thanks for some info!  I know not to bond the neutral anywhere else.  That was is done at the 200A.   I will have a ground from the sub to the 70a Disconnect via ground lug that I'll get at the hardware store.

Comment: Thanks for some info! I know not to bond the neutral anywhere else. That was is done at the 200A. I will have a ground from the sub to the 70a Disconnect via ground lug that I'll get at the hardware store. "Having no ground/earth at all to the RV connector is simply not allowed."  Well understood! Essentially a ground rod at the rv receptacle is mainly for  lightning & w/o a dedicated ground wire it doesn't protect from bad wiring etc.  I'll be running gfci breaker on this cuircut. This is for my property & It will get me by until I can run a dedicated ground to the RV plug. Thanks Again!

Comment: Yes, if you can't get a ground to the RV socket that is illegal (unless the installation is pre-1966), but GFCI protection for the circuit will help **A LOT** for practical safety.